# gtx 750TI with 334.21 nvidia drivers browser glitches

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia

i just installed latest 334.21 nvidia drivers from official site (.run file) and installed them. But now i am experiencing some graphic glitches in a firefox and thunderbird (before installing latest nvidia drivers i had no problems). Tried to turn off hardware acceleration didn't helped.

Looking for some help.

Comment: who the hell downvoted me? Tell me the reason

Answer (score 1):

The stable 337.25 driver is in Ubuntu repo ( may need to do $ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa) and is okay on 750ti, for Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 anyways.

Comment: There's a howto here: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/06/nvidia-driver-337-25/

Comment: There's not 337.25 driver in xorg-edgers repo :(

Comment: Installed 340.24 - same graphic glitch in a browser.